# Scala division by zero yields different results

Tags: java, scala, arithmetic-expressions, divide-by-zero

I am confused with how Scala handles division by zero. Here is a REPL code snippet.

```
scala> 1/0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  ... 33 elided

scala> 1.toDouble/0.toDouble
res1: Double = Infinity

scala> 0.0/0.0
res2: Double = NaN

scala> 0/0
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  ... 33 elided

scala> 1.toInt/0.toInt
java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
  ... 33 elided
```

As you can see in the above example, depending on how you divide by zero, you get one of the following:

- "java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero"
- "Double = NaN"
- "Double = Infinity"

This makes debugging quite challenging especially when dealing with data of unknown characteristics. What is the reasoning behind this approach, or even a better question, how to handle division by zero in a unified manner in Scala?

Comment: I think this has to do with the different datatypes. When performing different, yet related, calculations, try to always use the same datatypes. Eg.: Double, Int, etc

Comment: You may be dealing with data of unknown characteristics, but in a statically typed language like Scala you aren't dealing with data of unknown _type_.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I do understand what you mean. However, I guess most people would agree that this kind of approach is prone to some very dirty bugs as well as being very tedious to handle in every piece of arithmetic operation you write.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's all down to the division by zero rules for various types.

`0 / 0` is an *integer division by zero* (as both arguments are integer literals), and that is required to throw a `java.lang.ArithmeticException`.

`1.toDouble/0.toDouble` is a *floating point division by zero* with a positive numerator, and that is required to evaluate to `+Infinity`.

`0.0/0.0` is a floating point division by zero with a zero numerator, and that is required to evaluate to `+NaN`.

The first is a Java and Scala convention, the other two are properties of IEEE754 floating point, which is what Java and Scala both use.

Answer (score 5):

`Doubles` and `Floats` are `floating-point` values ([more here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic)) which can be represented as `+Infinity` `-Infinity` and `NaN` as defined in [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard.

`Integers` are `fixed numbers` which do not have any way of explicitly indicating invalid data, thus they throw `exceptions`

Unified solution to this would be to use `getOrElse` method on `Try`

```
Try(x/y).getOrElse(0)
```

In case you want to recover only on `ArithmeticException` you can use `recover` and `get`

```
Try(x/y).recover{ case _: ArithmeticException => 0 }.get
```

`recover` allows you to convert `Failure` to `Success`

You can also use `Try` to `Option` to return "no result" without showing exception

```
Try(x/y).toOption
```

Comment: Thanks. Your answer is quite helpful in that it elaborates on the possible solutions.

Comment: I have found `Try(1.0 / 0.0)` will return `Success(Infinity)` and not `Failure` and the `OrElse` isn't be returned.

Answer (score 1):

You can use partial functions for something like this. For example:

```
object MyObject {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {

        println(safeDiv.isDefinedAt(1.0, 1.0)) // true
        println(safeDiv.isDefinedAt(1.0, 0.0)) // false
        println(safeDiv(1.0, 1.0))             // 1.0 
        println(safeDiv(1.0, 0.0))             // crash

    }

    def safeDiv: PartialFunction[(Double, Double), Double] = { 
        case(a,b) if b != 0.0 => a/b 

    }   
}
```

Partial functions allow you to check whether the function is defined for a given input. In the example above, I said the the function `safeDiv` is not defined if the divisor is 0.0. Therefore you can check if the function will execute given the input. The check is not necessary, however `safeDiv(1.0, 0.0)` will not execute.

Partial functions is your friend against something like this:

```
scala> (1.0/0.0).toInt
res22: Int = 2147483647
```

Comment: Great. I think It will become handy