# Handling NULL values in Pyspark in Column expression

Tags: pyspark, isnull

I have been scratching my head with a problem in pyspark.

I want to conditionally apply a UDF on a column depending on if it is NULL or not. One constraint is that I do not have access to the DataFrame at the location I am writing the code I only have access to a column object.

Thus, I cannot simply do:

```
df.where(my_col.isNull()).select(my_udf(my_col)).toPandas()
```

Therefore, having only access to a Column object, I was writing the following:

```
my_res_col = F.when(my_col.isNull(), F.lit(0.0) \
              .otherwise(my_udf(my_col))
```

And then later do:

```
df.select(my_res_col).toPandas()
```

Unfortunately for some reason that I do not know, I sill receive NULLs in my UDF, forcing me to check for NULL values directly in my UDF.

I do not understand why the `isNull()` is not preventing rows with NULL values from calling the UDF.

Any insight on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

I thank you in advance for your help.

Antoine

Comment: Any chance you tried out the solution?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about your data. does it contains nan? spark handles null and nan differently.
[Differences between null and NaN in spark? How to deal with it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43882699/differences-between-null-and-nan-in-spark-how-to-deal-with-it)

so can you just try the below and check if it solves

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
my_res_col = F.when(((my_col.isNull())|(F.isnan(mycol))), F.lit(0.0)).otherwise(my_udf(my_col))
```