# Window function ignore nulls not working in Databricks

Tags: pyspark, databricks, spark-window-function

I am new to Databricks and was required to implement the snowflake code in Databricks.

The snowflake table, code and output look like below:

table:

| id | col1 | hn |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ee1 | null | 1 |
| ee1 | null | 2 |
| ee1 | test | 3 |
| ee1 | test | 4 |
| ee1 | test2 | 5 |

Query used:

```
SELECT ID, FIRST_VALUE(col1) ignore nulls OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY hn) AS first_value, LAST_VALUE(col1) ignore nulls OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY hn) AS last_value FROM table
```

Output:

| id | first_value | last_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ee1 | test | test2 |
| ee1 | test | test2 |
| ee1 | test | test2 |
| ee1 | test | test2 |
| ee1 | test | test2 |

When I tried the same query in Databricks using Spark SQL, ignore nulls did not work properly.

Can anyone provide the equivalent query for this in Databricks?

Comment: To handle null value comparisons, you can refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70394130/filtering-on-null-values-in-a-spark-dataframe-does-not-work-on-all-columns

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key point is the window frame specification:

```
SELECT ID, 
  FIRST_VALUE(col1) ignore nulls OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY hn) AS first_value, 
  LAST_VALUE(col1) ignore nulls OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY hn 
            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING) AS last_value 
FROM table;
```

If not defined explicitly the default is `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`